# Password management software with Active Directory based group permissions

Tags: password-manager, active-directory

I'm looking for the best free software to manage my passwords.

The features that I'm looking for are:

- The application should run as a server, so that several clients can access the password repositories.
- The application should offer the ability to organize the passwords into groups.
- It should be possible to define access rules to each group of passwords, or even each password item.

  - The access rules should be Active Directory based.
- Like I mentioned, for obvious reasons I prefer free (but secure) software, but depending on the advantages, non-free software is also an option.
- I prefer that the software is for Windows, but other OS are also a possibility.

I currently use [KeePass](http://keepass.info/), but it does not offer the ability to assign independent permissions.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Specifically, "the best" is subjective; you should provide objective requirements instead. // You might also wish to see [related questions on password-managers for Windows](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password-manager+windows).

Comment: Try LastPass - https://lastpass.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip Manu, but from what I've seen LastPass is cloud based, and I don't want my passwords to be stored outside my LAN.